# Breadcrumbs appear several times Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, breadcrumbs

I need your help please, I have a problem with the breadcrumbs of a particular view, in the index of the users view is repeated several times and I really do not know why it happens.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZg9A.png)

This my code:

```
<?php
$this->title = 'Usuarios';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'] = [$this->title];
?>
```

PD:  I'm using pajax

Comment: U can start Pjax container after this rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
$this->title = 'Usuarios';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have tried as you said, and the "Users" keeps popping up several times

Comment: then update your question and show your code  for the related  view and the code in layout where you configure the breadcrumbs widget  ..